# Direction of cross product between two vectors when theta>pi

Tags: discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I have two 3D vectors, `v1` and `v2`, that lay in the same plane in a 3D space. When calculating the cross product between them to find the normal to the plane, the right-hand rule applies for the direction of the resulting vector in the range of `theta = 0...pi` (considering that the angle is always counter-clockwise). However, when the angle between the two vectors is `theta > pi`, the direction swaps. This is a problem when I don't know the angle, and calculating the angle is not trivial. How can I prevent this, or fix the direction of the cross product for the whole range `0...2pi`?

Comment: There is a direct [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation) for the cross product of two vectors if you know their components.  Is that what you need?

Comment: Calculating the angle is, relatively speaking, very easy.  What constraint do you have that makes it hard?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to calculate the real angle, as in always counter-clockwise (as in my comment just added below). In order to do that I need the normal to the plane (as shown here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066933/direct-way-of-computing-clockwise-angle-between-2-vectors/16544330#16544330)). But how can I calculate the normal to the plane by having only the two vectors given without knowing the "real"/CCW angle, such that the direction of the normal doesn't change regardless on whether the angle is smaller or larger than pi?

Comment: There’s nothing intrinsic to the two vectors that you can use. The “real” angle you want—equivalently, which way is “up” for the plane of the vectors—can only be defined relative to some external reference. Try finding a concrete definition for why *you* would say that the angle between two vectors is $\gt pi$.

Comment: Thank you, amd. I guess there's no nice way to make this calculation more general than having that external reference. I'll think about it and see what I can do.

Comment: If you hold one vector fixed in a plane and rotate the other vector within the same plane, the direction of the cross product **should** reverse as the second vector rotates past the first vector or as the second vector rotates past the direction opposite the first vector. When the second vector is exactly in the same or opposite direction as the first vector, the cross product is zero, and there is no discontinuity. Perhaps you are trying to use a cross product for a job that it was never designed for.

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand rule still applies to $[-\pi,0]$ as well, if you interpret the angle between $\pi$ and $2\pi$ instead as an angle between $-\pi$ and $0$.

Maybe you should be content with the range $[-\pi,\pi]$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

The problem is that I don't know the real angle or the sign of the angle. Say, I have a vector `v1 = (1,0,0)` and a vector `v2 = (0,0,1)`. The angle between the two is 1/2pi and `v1 x v2 = (0,-1,0)`. If v2 changes to `v2 = (0,0,-1)`, the calculated angle is still 1/2pi, but the actual CCW angle is 3/2pi, and the cross product now changes the direction to `v1 x v2 = (0,1,0)`. How can I get the same cross product for both cases?

Comment: @user56574 I don't know what to tell you. Of course, you can do whatever weird thing you want after the cross product to get what you want, but the original cross product is not going to change. Why would you want this behavior that's inconsistent with the right hand rule anyway?

Comment: Not a problem. Maybe I just don't fully understand, and maybe the cross product isn't even the right way to approach this. All I want is a (normal) vector to two vectors that points in the same direction regardless of the angle between the two vectors.
Maybe I really need some external reference, as amd suggested above. Thank you for your help.